# scraping api protected by impreva

Tags: api, security, screen-scraping

I want to **scrape** an api, protected by "impreva" society,they use X-D-token in request header , and visid_incap_  incap_ses_* in response header.

now with datacenter proxy I get 200 response each 50 429 http response. even if I use only one concurent request. but with residential proxy I get 200.

is there any solution to bypass this protection by using only datacenter proxy ?

this is the request :

```
GET /api/magasins/72/navigation-content/ HTTP/2
Host: api.cora.fr
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36
Accept: application/vnd.api.v1+json
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Cora-Auth: apidrive
App-Id: 1
App-Signature: BROWSER;WEB;91.0.4472.114;;1.25.0;1;2;Chrome;1080;1920
X-D-Token: 3:R3wmbBvTR1D6vDBmzCLerA==:qzf5V/qwmQQShcP5/cFIjM/goahseigjk/Xs2H5btwW5kCw+nLSNStvZUdugaCm1WIVl4vGCwXFf8Te0GueaZV3koYe2oCe7YiDelKihZ5LSVVz3T6uNKMaOxpSFD+CIP6usg48ioqTCv/Wme5hdCQ8n7b5qR25xWKhFCYesCoYZnen2LHVOVnMWde6AkItRarRDG5IcEUW0XYyojX9i+XL6X3Mgnynvsb7l6wVVW4AruNE80MiLkSgo2XHlh3SBFArXBdBvvyKUpfRUGZokMqYDIS03w/ShB1OJ4KUfKs6Wu1hrNCZlY3N8RTE/S8oYAsjpagWzQwTuCTwCLtYv+48kvXRIihtHC1IQ5nRPsd7s4TuanGYsYDjm3CMaUpvA+pQIqLTiLUYdG+lIMfYXUpQpGOXC+2gF69yxyFQbtxpbluv7NsHELoaaLQHvoYKI:JA3UaEpTRK6Wjf6b6yXbvJ28p7vjimPImMsmAN8GEmI=
Uuid: 2bb3d0ad-04c1-485a-a98d-4ac3d753fd1b
Origin: https://www.cora.fr
Referer: https://www.cora.fr/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Te: trailers
```

this is  the response  429 :

```
HTTP/2 429 Too Many Requests
Date: Mon, 27 Sep 2021 13:08:36 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Server: api.cora.fr
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.cora.fr
Vary: Origin
Set-Cookie: nlbi_2346747=ozjvaL0oPg66DB86rtkoMQAAAAA9QXZBJ+NCBIVB3SmXJNXF; path=/; 
Domain=.cora.fr; Secure; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: 
visid_incap_2346747=70eYj3uqQcKlyni2K4A651PCUWEAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD3srVYiHapPbOcjTfZu3h0; 
expires=Tue, 27 Sep 2022 10:34:34 GMT; HttpOnly; path=/; Domain=.cora.fr; Secure; 
SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: 
incap_ses_1099_2346747=FIAFfin/tmOLYnuIJm9AD1PCUWEAAAAA/xhZaPz5UshGvjEiQfzp2w==; 
path=/; Domain=.cora.fr; Secure; SameSite=None
X-Cdn: Imperva
X-Iinfo: 0-27795484-27795152 pNYN RT(1632748115671 0) q(0 0 0 0) r(1 1) U5

{"message": "429 Too Many Requests","429}
```

this is the header of response 200 :

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Mon, 27 Sep 2021 14:13:10 GMT
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 10
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 9
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 
Etag: W/"09af7903630eefe87a18365ff527e6917bac5da1"
Server: api.cora.fr
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.cora.fr
Vary: Origin
Set-Cookie: 
nlbi_2346747=FsJOKpMDRQqeSktYrtkoMQAAAADB426mJ/c0BiDBDsyETwFU; 
path=/; Domain=.cora.fr; Secure; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: visid_incap_2346747=Dsbf9nV0RN+yazh0zGE893bRUWEAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD6RV43J8UcxEZJHt07UrHN; expires=Tue, 27 Sep 2022 08:49:53 GMT; HttpOnly; path=/; Domain=.cora.fr; Secure; SameSite=None;
Set-Cookie: incap_ses_476_2346747=qsgAeXWGFRc+6OUn+BebBnbRUWEAAAAAimqhOCYEdQHug9mxUEC0wA==; path=/; Domain=.cora.fr; Secure; SameSite=None
X-Cdn: Imperva
X-Iinfo: 10-120722009-120615528 pNNN RT(1632751989673 0) q(0 0 0 -1) r(4 4) U5
```

Comment: "*is there any solution to bypass this protection*" If there was, wouldn't it be pretty pointless to have any protection in the first place...? This provider obviously doesn't want you using their API like this, have you considered contacting them? `429 Too Many Requests` indicates that you're sending the requests too quickly, why not just throttle the request rate...?

Comment: I use one concurent request so it's not a  fast crawler. And when I use  residiantial proxy  I don't get 429 response, now I wan't to get the same result without using residiendial proxy, just datacenter proxy

Comment: or find a relation between x-d-token and visid_incap and  incap_ses, or decode  x-d-token , I tried  base64 decoder to decode first part of x-d-token but didn't work